# MapReduce: Reducer is not getting invoked in Custom Input Format program. Iidentity reducer is getting called inspite custom reducer is configured

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

As a beginner,I was trying to implement a custom input format program. Till Mapper, it is working fine but instead of the Reducer i implemented, default reducer is getting invoked (Same output of Mapper is getting printed in file part-r-0000).

**I have checked the signature of the program. Also key and value classes for both phases are given correctly. Even the number of reducer task is also given.**

I was not able to find why reducer was not getting executed. I have checked the other threads as well, but no luck.

**Driver**

```
package cif;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

 public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int exitCode=ToolRunner.run(new Driver(), args);
    System.out.println(" Program Ends :: Exit Code ="+exitCode);

   }

 @Override
 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Job job= Job.getInstance(getConf());

    job.setInputFormatClass(XmlInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(CifMapper.class);

    job.setReducerClass(CifReducer.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(CifReducer.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(4);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));


    FileSystem fs=FileSystem.get(getConf());
    if(fs.exists(new Path(args[1]))){
        fs.delete(new Path(args[1]), true);
    }

    return job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;     

    }
  }
```

**XMLInputFormat File**

```
   package cif;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;

 public class XmlInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text,Text>{

 @Override
  protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext c, Path file){
        return true;
  }



  @Override
  public RecordReader<Text, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit split,
        TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,     InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Enter CreateRecord");
    XmlRecordReader reader=new XmlRecordReader();
    reader.initialize(split, context);


    return reader;
    }
```

}

**XMLRecordReader**

```
 package cif;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader;




public class XmlRecordReader extends RecordReader<Text,Text> {


  public String startTag="<Employee>";
  public String endTag="</Employee>";
  public String eidStartTag ="<eid>";
  public String eidEndTag="</eid>";
  public String locationStartTag="<location>";
  public String locationEndTag="</location>";

public static String v="";

public static int startTagSync=0;

public Text key = new Text();
public Text value = new Text();
LineRecordReader lineReader;
public LongWritable lineKey;


public XmlRecordReader() throws IOException{


}


@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    this.lineReader=new LineRecordReader();
    this.lineReader.initialize(split, context);

}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    lineReader.close();     
}

@Override
public Text getCurrentKey() throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    //System.out.println("returning key : "+key);
    return key;
}



@Override
public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //System.out.println(" Returning value :"+ value);
    return value;
}

@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    return lineReader.getProgress();
}



@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        //System.out.println(" Enter nextKeyValue");


        if(!lineReader.nextKeyValue()){

            System.out.println("End of File");
            return false;
        }


        String line=lineReader.getCurrentValue().toString();

        if(line.contains(startTag))
            ++startTagSync;
        while(startTagSync>0){

            lineReader.nextKeyValue();

            //System.out.println("key "+lineReader.getCurrentKey());

            line=lineReader.getCurrentValue().toString();
            //System.out.println(" line --"+line);

            if(line.contains(endTag))
                --startTagSync;
            if(startTagSync>0){

                if(line.contains(eidStartTag)){

                    line=line.substring(eidStartTag.length()+2);
                    int index=line.indexOf(eidEndTag);
                    v=line.substring(0, index);
                    value.set(new Text(line.substring(0, index)));
                //  System.out.println(line);


                }

                if(line.contains(locationStartTag)){
                    line.trim();
                    line=line.substring(locationStartTag.length()+2);
                /// System.out.println("line :"+line);
                    int index=line.indexOf(locationEndTag);
                    //key.set(new Text(line.substring(0,index)));
                    v=line.substring(0,index);
                    key.set(new Text(v));

                }



            }



        }


    return true;
}
```

}

**CifMapper**

```
 package cif;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


public class CifMapper extends Mapper<Text,Text,Text,IntWritable>{

public static IntWritable one= new IntWritable(1);



  public void map(Text key,Text value,Context context)throws     IOException,InterruptedException{

    //System.out.println("Entering Mapper");
    context.write(new Text(key.toString()), one);
    System.out.println("Exiting mapper ::"+key.toString() +" "+one);


    }
 }
```

**CifReducer**

```
package cif;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class CifReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {

   public int count;

    public void reducer(Text key,Iterable <IntWritable> values,Context  context) throws Exception{

    System.out.println(" entering reducer");
    count=0;
    Iterator<IntWritable> iter=values.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        iter.next();
        count++;
    }

    context.write(key,new IntWritable(count));
    System.out.println(" Exiting reducer");
    }

}
```

**Input**

```
  <Employee>
    <eid>1</eid>
    <location>Bangalore</location>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <eid>2</eid>
    <location>Bangalore</location>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <eid>3</eid>
    <location>BangaloreNorth</location>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <eid>4</eid>
    <location>Chennaii</location>
  </Employee>
```

**Output**

```
Bangalore   1
Bangalore   1
BangaloreNorth  1
Chennaii    1
Chennaii    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Java overriding rule:

> The overriding method must not throw new or broader checked exceptions.

your reduce method is throwing `Exception` i.e. it is doing broadning of checked exception.

```
public void reducer(Text key,Iterable <IntWritable> values,Context  context) throws Exception{
```

**in place of this it should be:**

```
public void reducer(Text key,Iterable <IntWritable> values,Context  context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

Comment: Issue was, by mistake I wrote 'reducer' instead of "reduce"                                                                                                           public void reducer(Text key,Iterable <IntWritable> values,Context  context) throws Exception

Answer (score 0):

Extremely sorry for the silly mistake.But thought of putting it as it might help someone

```
 public void reducer(Text key,Iterable <IntWritable> values,Context  context) throws Exception
```

has to be replaced with

```
 public void reduce(Text key,Iterable <IntWritable> values,Context  context) throws Exception
```

**Instead of overriding reduce method, i wrote reducer hence it was not called.**